# Statue and a flag distances

Tags: trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Next to a flagpole is a statue that measures 9m high. The upper end of the flagpole with the bottom of the statue form an angle of 53.13 degrees to the floor, and the upper end of the flagpole to the top of the statue makes an angle of 59 degrees from the horizontal.

What is the height of the mast and how far is the statue ?

I tried using the tangent function and solving the system, but it seems that this is wrong

$tan(59)=((y-9)/x)$ and $tan(53.13)=(y/x)$

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "shaft"?

Comment: I meant flagpole

Comment: It looks like you've assumed that the flagpole is taller than the statue. Is this assumption supported in the problem in any way?

Comment: It is the only way that it makes sense to me, only if the statue is smaller than the flagpole